# Keep column titles when exporting SQL query in MapInfo

Tags: mapinfo, sql, query, table

Is there a way to keep column titles when exporting a query in MapInfo as a csv or a new tab. This is my result:

[image]

And my export looks like this:

[image]

It's not a major issue, I jus like saving myself time wherever I can.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply add the alias in quotes after the column name.

[image]